# Problems mapping network drive in Windows 8

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, network-shares, nas

I recently bought a NAS drive ([My Book Live](http://wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280)), and it's working great from my iPad, Windows 7 PCs, and OSX, but I have a problem on Windows 8.

Each time I map a network drive I'm prompted for a user/password by Windows, it always tells me the password is incorrect. But if I keep on retrying (just by hitting enter over and over) it will work after about 10 retries.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my username/password for windows 8 set to the same as my username/password for my MBL share. To fix the problem I just needed to change the username on the MBL, now it's working.